# Scala: check generic existential type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics, type-erasure, existential-type

I have a Scala library method that I need to override:

```
def transform(dataset: Dataset[_]): DataFrame
```

What I want to do: in my overridden implementation, check if `_ is MyType`. If yes, cast `dataset` to `Dataset[MyType]`. If not, throw an exception saying `type ActualTypeOf_ is not supported`.

There's only one `MyType` I care about. Obviously, I can't rewrite the library to change method's signature.

Comment: You cannot check against the erased type. I don't know how Dataset works, but maybe you can look at the first "element" in it and check the runtime type of that?

Comment: how does Dataset look like?

Comment: It's Spark https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html

Are you suggesting `if (dataset.head.isInstanceOf[MyType]) {..}` ?

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed in a comments section to the question `Dataset` is actually Spark Dataset.
To be honest, I'm not the Spark expert, but from the doc I see there is method which allows to get `Classtag` for type `T` (as far as I understand) : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#classTag--

So, I think your solution might look like:

```
override def transform(dataset: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = {
 val dataClass = dataset.classTag.runtimeClass
 if (dataClass == classOf[MyType]) {
   val myTypeDataset = dataset.as[MyType]
   // further handling of `myTypeDataset`
 } else {
   throw new RuntimeException(s"type $dataClass is not supported")
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting. For some reason, I'm getting this error when trying to call classTag:

`error: value classTag is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_$1]
           val dataClass = dataset.classTag().runtimeClass`

Could it be because classTag is declared as a generic method? Scala 2.11.12, Spark 2.4.3...

Comment: @ptkvsk Perhaps, this is bug in JavaDoc generating tool, because `classTag` is private method in companion object - https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L252 - please, ignore my answer and excuse me for confusing you.